# When and why did “baron” start to be used figuratively?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, figurative

***[Baron](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/baron)*** is a title of nobility which generally refers to

> a member of the lowest grade of nobility.

but a more recent usage is:

> You can use baron to refer to someone who controls a large amount of a particular industry or activity and who is therefore extremely powerful.
>
> - ...the battle against the drug barons.
> - ...the British press barons

the figurative usage (powerful person in an industry) appears to contrast with the original sense (lowest grade of nobility), but when did this usage start? Was it an AmE or a BrE usage? And, possibly, why baron and not other higher ranking titles of nobility?

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/baron) provides no information about this usage.

(also  *King* is used metaphorically but sense is different.)

Comment: Also, ['robber barons'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/robber) from the late 19th c US. Exactly why is a difficult question to answer especially if some one guy just started using it metaphorically.

Comment: @Mitch - were barons, among other nobles, the first to enter the world of industry?

Comment: Wikipedia gives a lot of detail on *robber barons*.

Comment: I only have suspicions that the first author to coin the phrase chose one lower on the hierarchy because it sounded vaguely appropriate.

Comment: One might surmise that the lower you are on the hierarchy, the less of an estate there is to inherit and the more likely it is to need to supplement ones income by actual work, thus supporting the metaphor even if in reality no industrialist ever came from the nobility.Those actual so-called robber barons mostly came from the working class.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robber_baron_(feudalism)

Comment: All noble titles come from metaphors. A count was originally a companion. A duke was a leader. A prince stood first. A baron was an outstanding warrior, and the root appears to be Germanic, not Romance like most titles.

Comment: The nobles who compelled King John of England to agree in 1215 to the Magna Carta are always described as "barons". That was long before the carefully graded system of barons, viscounts, earls, marquesses, dukes etc. had been devised. In 1215 the barons, whatever their formal title, ruled their own territories and did not particularly recognise the power of the king, who was in theory their overlord. I have managed organisations in which some of my subordinates behaved similarly. I regarded them as "barons".

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=robber+baron%2C+land+baron&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crobber%20baron%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cland%20baron%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crobber%20baron%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cland%20baron%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Lord" is used in the same way: "drug lords", "crime lords", etc.